# In a Nativescript Angular app, where is application.start()/run()?

Tags: javascript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm looking at the Nativescript 4.0 changes listed in [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Iia0yEr5seq4H9qk4oMuJs4-M8dgmne98fymCO5IczA/edit#) and it says that `application.start()` is being deprecated for `application.run()`. I've downloaded the `nativescript-template-ng-tutorial` and am looking at all the files but I don't see where `application.start()` is being called.

Where is this being called?

Comment: @RandyCasburn it definitely lists them as methods in the changelog

Comment: Yeah - saw that. That's why I deleted my comment. The only place I found it is the tests/main.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called in nativescript-angular

likely related: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/1274

Comment: Found it in platform-common.js in nativescript-angular!